# NuxtJS sometimes gives welcome page

Tags: nuxt.js

I have web app based on: NodeJS, nginx, PHP, Percona, Redis and NuxtJS. All of them are running in separate docker containers. The problem I am facing is that mostly it shows the web app, but sometimes it gives me NuxtJS welcome page. Nothing is changed in the meantime.

I don't know why sometimes I get welcome page instead of the web app.

The welcome page text is:

```
Welcome to your Nuxt Application
We recommend you take a look at the Nuxt documentation, whether you are new or have previous experience with the framework.

To get started, remove components/Tutorial.vue and start coding in pages/index.vue. Have fun!
```

As it is NuxtJS app I don't see anything in logs, any logging is not present in the container (lack of plugin), only start of the web app.

Comment: Does it happen when you do have JS disabled? Also, could you give us a [repro] or more context here? It's pretty difficult to debug an app without more context. Do you have the same behavior outside of Docker?

Comment: @kissu Yes, when JS is disabled it behaves the same. I cannot share more details as I am restricted by agreement. What do you mean by "outside of Docker"?

Comment: The same? It means that it sometimes prompts you the message? Or all the time? A [repro] is not the actual project, just a reproduction (no agreement issues here). Outside of Docker, is you running a Nuxt app outside of the container, without Docker. Just trying to narrow down the issue here. Docker is a layer of complexity on top of Nuxt here, the first thing is to find if it is coming from Nuxt, Docker, or something else.

Comment: @kissu the same means sometimes the web app is loaded and sometimes the NuxtJS welcome page is loaded. Each page reload (F5 or Ctrl+F5) gives one page or other, randomly. I am running NuxtJS in docker container. I cannot get it out of the container. I checked one thing: when I stop one of the front-ends the problem seems to be solved, but how is it possible that there were two front-ends working at the same time?

Comment: You can extract the app and create a project out of the container, nothing unfeasible so far. One of the FE? Don't you have only Nuxt as a FE? You maybe run 2 instances at the same time, with the same port?

Comment: @kissu I am new to this app. Seems like there were two different FE instances running on the same port and that's why sometimes NuxtJS welcome page was loaded. Seems like the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two different instances of front-end running on the same port. Stopping one of them has solved the problem.

However I don't know how it is possible that two different containers run on the same port.